# Use awk to selectively zero left-pad certain fields only

Tags: awk

My file has the following format:

```
1/2/2559,11:58:00,4/1/2559,09:36:04,10,55,My Name
```

I want to only to use awk to (among other things) left-pad with zero only the 6th column.

For e.g., the output may be:

```
My Name,1/2/2559/11:58:00,10,0055,4/1/2559,09:35:04
```

So in my example above, both 5th and 6th columns are number fields but I only want to left pad one of the fields.

The printf examples I got from other posts so far (say using `printf ($7,$1,$2,$5,"%04d\n",$6,$3,$4)` seems to scope in all fields or terminates the current row upon reaching the field to be left-padded.

Would appreciate some pointers on this, thanks.

Comment: Your might want to study how printf works. Is not that difficult and its (almost) the same syntax in all languages: awk, bash, C, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't match the expected output you posted but I don't see how you could get that from the input you posted so this MAY be what you're looking for:

```
$ awk -F, '{printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%04d,%s,%s\n",$7,$1,$2,$5,$6,$3,$4}' file
My Name,1/2/2559,11:58:00,10,0055,4/1/2559,09:36:04
```

If not then edit your question to explain the mapping between your sample input and the expected output.

Consider also:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$6=sprintf("%04d",$6)} 1' file
1/2/2559,11:58:00,4/1/2559,09:36:04,10,0055,My Name
```

Comment: I see, got it. So basically, if I were to specify the formatting for one field, I need to specify for all of them. That would make my command very long (my actual script has about 50 fields) but I guess if it needs to be done it needs to be done. If you know a way to only have to specify the formatting for one field alone, would appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, it's trivial but it all depends what you mean by that. Your current problem has 2 parts - 1) formatting 1 field, and 2) rearranging multiple field. The best solution will depend on what percentage of fields you are rearranging.

Comment: Yes, I understand your explanation now. I found that using printf for my output may not be the best solution. Right now, I've found a better solution for myself by assigning the formatted number to a variable for each line {a = sprintf("%04d",$6)} and then printing the variable in a general print() statement at the end. But in the context of my poorly framed question, your answer is correct :)